# Counting descendants(Child nodes) of a tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have the following tree structure with nodes first child and next sibling

```
public class Node 
{
 public Node firstChild;
 public Node nextSibling;
}
```

I am trying to write a function that can count all the descendents of a node. I just want to know if my approach is correct

```
public int descendentsCount (Node node)

  {

    if(node.firstChild == null && node.nextSibling ==null)
    return 0;

    else if(node.firstChild == null && node.nextSibling!=null)
    node = node.nextSibling;

    count ++; // count is static 

    descendentsCount(node.firstChild);
    return count;

  }
```

Comment: You should try it. I'd suggest that you draw a tree with pen and paper and try to follow your code with the help of that drawing and see what happens. You might also want to check out graph traversal on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int descendentsCount (Node node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    return subTreeCount(node) - 1; // exclude node from count
}

// counts nodes in subtree (including node)
public static int subTreeCount(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
         return 0;
    }
    int count = 1; // include node in count

    // add subtree sizes of all children
    Node child = node.firstChild;
    while (child != null) {
        count += subTreeCount(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int descendentsCount(Node node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
          return 0;
        }
        return subTreeCount(node.firstChild);
    }

    public static int subTreeCount(Node node)
    {
        // base case 
        if (node == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // process all children and siblings
        return 1 + subTreeCount(node.firstChild) + subTreeCount(node.nextSibling);
    }
```